# SQL Compare and filter multiple columns into rows

Tags: mysql, sql

Ok so I have a table(MyTable) that looks like this:

```
value1 | value2 | value3 | value4  | value5  | date
---------------------------------------------------------
   1   |    4   |   6    |    25   |   35    | 2011-10-07
---------------------------------------------------------
   2   |    3   |   6    |    25   |   14    | 2011-10-01
---------------------------------------------------------
```

My end goal is to get one column with every unique number and latest asocciated date like:

```
combinedValues  | date
----------------------------
       1        | 2011-10-07
----------------------------
       4        | 2011-10-07
----------------------------
       6        | 2011-10-07
----------------------------
       25       | 2011-10-07
----------------------------
       35       | 2011-10-07
----------------------------
       2        | 2011-10-01
----------------------------
       3        | 2011-10-01
----------------------------
       14       | 2011-10-01
----------------------------
```

So far I've gotten it to work with this query, but with one column only:

```
SELECT t.value1, t.date
FROM MyTable t
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT value1, MAX( date ) AS LatestDate
  FROM MyTable
  GROUP BY value1
)tm ON t.value1= tm.value1
AND t.date = tm.LatestDate
GROUP BY value1
ORDER BY date DESC
```

So how would I go about this to accomplish the table with combinedValues? Is it even possible?

Comment: you should give sqlfiddle.com link for such problem..so that we can get problem quickly and you can get response quick.

Comment: example of sqlfiddle : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/96236

Comment: Ah thanks, you beat me to it. Actually did not know a sql fiddle existed, thanks!

Comment: I wondered how to get how many of those where even and odd numbers and came up with this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d3f7a/1/0)
---------------

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this query:

```
Select val,Max(date) date From
(Select value1 as val,date From MyTable
Union All
Select value2 as val,date From MyTable
Union All
Select value3 as val,date From MyTable
Union All
Select value4 as val,date From MyTable
Union All
Select value5 as val,date From MyTable)tab
Group by val order by date desc,val;
```

### [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bc36a/1)

Comment: Works awesome, thanks!

Just had to order by Max(date), instead of just date for it to work with my actual db setup

Comment: How would I go about to count even and odd numbers i.e. two columns with two rows, even and odd with their associated sum/count